# Intersect, But Only Matching Types

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need a solution for the following problem.
I have an array, but there are various types data in it.
Example: [1,2,'string1','string2']

I need a function that does intersection, but for only the matching types.
This is what I mean:

```
intersect([1,2,'string1','string2'],['string2','string3']) // [1,2,'string2']
intersect([1,2,'string1','string2'],[2,3]) // [2,'string1','string2']
```

The second argument is always the same type, it is not mixed.
I have this:

```
function intersect(a, b) {
    var t;
    if (b.length > a.length) t = b, b = a, a = t; // indexOf to loop over shorter
    return a.filter(function (e) {
        return b.indexOf(e) > -1;
    });
}
```

but it always removes the other type too :(

Comment: You can use lodash `intersection` method for it.

Comment: I think calling this intersection is quite misleading, you seem to want to remove any array items from the first array that are the same type as (but do not match) the second array. Is that correct? (And also, will the second array always be only a single type?)

Comment: Are you sure the examples are correct? Intersection of collections / arrays means the elements that are common in both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function intersect(a, b) {
    var t;
    if (b.length > a.length) t = b, b = a, a = t; // indexOf to loop over shorter
    
    const type = typeof(b[0]); //check the type of the second array's first element since each element has the same type

    const tempArray = a.filter(function (e) {
      return typeof(e) !== type;
    }); //filter the first array if it has different item types than the second array's elements

    return tempArray.concat(a.filter(function (e) {
        return b.indexOf(e) > -1;
    }));
}

console.log(intersect([1,2,'string1','string2'],['string2','string3'])) // [1,2,'string2']
```